# LocalDateTime class in Java and Period

Tags: java, period, localdatetime

Have such a simple Java class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 11, 26, 15, 38);
      Period period = Period.ofYears(1).ofMonths(2).ofDays(3);
      dateTime = dateTime.minus(period);
      System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
}
```

Which results in `2017-11-23T15:38`
Can someone explain me, why a date is subtracted while year and months - doesn't?

Comment: You are calling static methods from an instance. This is not recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because each three method

> (ofYears(1) & `ofMonths(2)` & ofDays(3))

returns an instance of Period class

Each time you call another method value in `Period period` gets overriden.

If say ofYears(1) return instance of Period class named a then `ofMonths(2)` also return a new instance and override he initial one. So, the last one remains and stored to the `period` variable.

That's why only the `ofDays(3)` is showing effect.

If you want to do the same you should try calling below method

```
`public static Period of(int years,
                        int months,
                        int days)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple.

Each of the methods, ofYears, ofMonths and ofDays return a new instance of period.
So effectively your period is equal to **Period.ofDays(3)**

This is not a builder pattern, where you keep modifying the same instance.

In order to achieve what you need, this code will do the work:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 11, 26, 15, 38);
    Period period = Period.of(1, 2, 3);
    dateTime = dateTime.minus(period);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

prints out

```
2016-09-23T15:38
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it works like `Period.ofDays(3)` overridden every time since they are static method.

Use [Period of(int years,int months,int days)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#of-int-int-int-)

```
dateTime = dateTime.minus(Period.of(1, 2, 3));
```

Or you can use `withDays`, `withMonths`, `withYears` like for chaining

Answer (score 1):

> Give a Man a Fish, and You Feed Him for a Day. Teach a Man To Fish,
> and You Feed Him for a Lifetime.

(It certainly goes for a woman too.)

I am trying to teach you to fish. I am explaining how to catch such an error without having to ask on Stack Overflow first.

Set up your IDE to warn you when you use an object (an instance) for calling a static method. That is whenever you do something like

```
    yourObject.someStaticMethod();
```

In my Eclipse your code gives this warning:

> The static method ofDays(int) from the type Period should be accessed
> in a static way

This tells us that `ofDays()` is a static method, and therefore the result of the call is the same as calling `Period.ofDays(3)`. Eclipse even offers to fix the problem for me:

[image]

After I click “Change access to static using Period (declaring type)”, that code line becomes:

```
    Period.ofYears(1).ofMonths(2);
    Period period = Period.ofDays(3);
```

Now I think you can see why you got the result you got.

So:

1. Make sure your IDE is configured to issue such warnings. It doesn’t have to be Eclipse, other IDEs can do the same.
2. Read those warnings when you get them and make sure you understand them. If you've skipped a warning once, if you get an unexpected result, go back and read the warning again. If you still need to ask on Stack Overflow, you're welcome of course, and consider including the text of that warning you didn't understand.

Others have nicely explained how to fix your code to give you your desired result. If `Period.of(1, 2, 3)` is a bit confusing because you can't tell what's years, months weeks and days, use `Period.ofYears(1).plusMonths(2).plusDays(3)`, and everything is clear. It also resembles what you tried in the question.

**Link:** [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) with many tips similar to the one I am giving here (and not because yours was a poor question, it’s a good one, I upvoted it).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that all classes in the `java.time` package are immutable [(see Java Docs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Instances of `Period` cannot be changed after creation, you will have to create a new instance and reassign it.

This is the reason why only the last `Period.ofDays(3)` has an effect on the result (as previous answers suggest). And it is also the reason why `withDays` returns a copy of the respective Period.